# How to display data horizontally?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table and i want to display data as horizontally by dates
the first table has staff names(staff table) , and the second one has booking details(booking table)  both are joined together with the Staff_id key.

I have created an outer loop that gets all staff name , and an inner loop that gets bookings by staff id and displays them horizontally by dates , And that's where I'm stack as nothing is being placed in the right TD's dates .
I have tried to control where data goes using mysql(DAYOFWEEK)  to no avail.

**Here is what i want**

[image]

Here is the code Im Currently using

```
<table class="table">
              <tr>
                <th>Staff</th>
                <th>Mon</th>
                <th>Tue</th>
                <th>Wen</th>
                <th>Thur</th>
                <th>Fri</th>
                <th>Sat</th>
                <th>Sun</th>
              </tr> 
                    <?php   
                      $sql ="select * from Staff";
                      $result = $controler->db_connection->query($sql);
                     while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
                     ?>
              <tr>
          


                 <td><?php echo $row['firstName']; ?>
                     <br>
                     <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
                 </td>
       <?php  // Loop to get staff 
                $bookingsql = 'select id,staff_id, shift_start,DAYOFWEEK(shift_start) as dayz, week(shift_start) as week from shiftbooking where week(shift_start) = 33 and Staff_id ='.$row['id'];

                $bookresult = $controler->db_connection->query($bookingsql);
                while($rows = $bookresult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
                 //This is the Area Im getting Stack 
                          
                   if($rows['dayz'] == 2):// Monday td?>
                   
                    <td> 
                   
                  Start Time   <?php echo $rows['shift_start']; ?>

                    </td>
                <?php else:?>

                <td>  </td>
                <?php endif;?>



                      <?php   if($rows['dayz'] == 3)://Tue   td?>
                   
                   <td> 
                  
                   Start Time   <?php echo $rows['shift_start']; ?>
                   </td>
                   <?php else:?>

                    <td>  </td>
               <?php endif;?>
                       
        <?php endwhile;
                            //End the Area Im getting Stack 
                        
                        ?>
        </tr>   


              <?php endwhile; ?>                                               
           
       </table>
```

The result from the inner loop is

```
Array
(
    [id] => 29
    [Staff_id] => 10
    [shift_start] => 2021-08-21 12:06:00
    [dayz] => 7
    [week] => 33
    [location]=>Ground 
)

Array
(
    [id] => 30
    [Staff_id] => 10
    [shift_start] => 2021-08-21 02:00:00
    [dayz] => 7
    [week] => 33
    [location]=>second floor
)

Array
(
    [id] => 36
    [Staff_id] => 10
    [shift_start] => 2021-08-21 04:00:00
    [dayz] => 7
    [week] => 33
    [location]=>second floor
)

Array
(
    [id] => 48
    [Staff_id] => 10
    [shift_start] => 2021-08-15 14:00:00
    [dayz] => 1
    [week] => 33
    [location]=>second floor
)
```

Comment: Hello kariuki, can you please explain the problem that you're actually facing? You mentioned the problem is in the **inner loop**, so can you show us the result that you get from this code?

Comment: The problem is the horizontal  <td > of Mon - Sun  which is the inner loop  grows bigger in number . i need them to be 7 in number (Mon-Fri) and all the data E.G all the monday booking to go on Monday <TD> and soo on .

Comment: If only I can find away of  clossing the <td> when all the booking for e.g monday  has been fetched , that will sort my problem

Comment: From the picture you attached, each staff has one booking per day, but that's not the case isn't it? There might be multiple bookings on the same day for the same staff?

Comment: Yes,  there might be multiple bookings on the same day for the same staf

Comment: I NcXNaV  , I have just double checked it will be one booking per day per staff Sorry about that

Comment: Okay, then by using your method with `if()` statement, I guess it will work out? SInce there will only be one booking per day per staff? That means per week, there'll be a maximum of 7 bookings, one each day for each staff right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236065/discussion-between-ncxnav-and-kariuki).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a week planner, for visualizing what multiple staff are doing across 7 days.

```
SELECT * FROM Staff
```

You are pulling back each staff member, but not ordering, or checking the year.
Personally I might have used BETWEEN and not done two checks, but...

```
SELECT
    id,
    staff_id,
    shift_start,
    DAYOFWEEK(shift_start) as dayz,
    WEEK(shift_start) as week 
FROM shiftbooking
WHERE WEEK(shift_start) = ? AND YEAR(shift_start) = ? AND Staff_id = ?
ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK(shift_start) ASC
```

I'd also look at using MySQL parameterized queries, so that the staff ID is not a vector for SQL injection. Nobody will thank you if they get hacked. [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

This might work, but is also something called an N+1 query problem, as you are querying within an inner loop.

You could try a common table expression, or [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

```
WITH working_staff AS (
    SELECT
            S.id,
            S.firstName,
            COUNT(SB.id) AS booking_count
        FROM `staff` AS S
            JOIN `shiftbooking` AS SB ON SB.staff_id = S.id
        WHERE WEEK(SB.shift_start) = ?
            AND YEAR(SB.shift_start) = ?
        GROUP BY S.id, S.firstName
)
SELECT
    SB.id,
    SB.staff_id,
    working_staff.firstName,
    SB.shift_start,
    DAYOFWEEK(SB.shift_start) as dayz,
    WEEK(SB.shift_start) as week,
    SB.location
FROM `shiftbooking` AS SB
    JOIN working_staff ON working_staff.id = SB.staff_id
WHERE WEEK(SB.shift_start) = ? AND YEAR(SB.shift_start) = ?
ORDER BY SB.shift_start ASC
```

> I used 33 and 2021 as values, (33, 2021, 33, 2021) as there are 4 params.

You don't even need to foreach through days using this method, but you could use `array_filter` to grab the exact bookings you need. [php array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter) so that you get a sub-set of a specific day per-week (which you could show, as a html ordered list)

Also FYI the schema should be provided to best help with SQL, as you may be missing indexes or have a specific implied setup (like the location field, which is not part of your shared queries)

```
CREATE TABLE `shiftbooking` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `staff_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `shift_start` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `location` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
ALTER TABLE `test`.`shiftbooking` 
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX `staff_at_time` (`staff_id` ASC, `shift_start` ASC) VISIBLE;
;

CREATE TABLE `staff` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I've not inferred foreign keys, or a location table (which would be further worked into CTE). I did make sure you're staff represented a single person, so they can only be allocated at a start_time once (ignoring end-time); You'd get one query result for all days, and use `array_filter` to only return true if the `$value` matched the day of week.

Comment: Thanks It was a weekly planner and I used array_filter  after destructuring  the aray .